# Get return status from Background Tasks in FastAPI

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi

I have an API which posts jobs upon which background jobs are created and I want to send status of job on another GET api. How to achieve this? In `background_work()` function I am going with multiprocessing as call internally targets `subprocess.call()` calls.

```
from fastapi import BackgroundTasks, FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

def background_work(data: str):
    # some computation on data and return it
    return status

@app.post("/post_job", status_code=HTTP_201_CREATED)
async def send_notification(data: str, background_tasks: BackgroundTasks):
    background_tasks.add_task(background_work, data)
    return {"message": "Job Created, check status after some time!"}

@app.get("/get_status")
def status():
    #how to return status of job submitted to background task
```

Comment: Also, I have gone through different questions asked on fastapi github - and suggest to go with tools like celery etc. Is this task can be achieved on simple fastapi

Comment: What do you want to do with the return status?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This currently cannot be achieved with FastAPI, since Background Tasks are just references to callables to be invoked after your Response is sent, they do not store any kind of status.

You will have to use Celery or another library.

Comment: You may also try to give a look at WPS (Web Processing Service) - PyWPS is one of its Python implementations. PyWPS can run as a separate service and `owslib.wps.WPSExecution` can be used from inside your FastAPI App to control the status of your WPS process.

Answer (score 22):

I'm using fastAPI exactly like this, combining `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor()` and asyncio to manage long running jobs.

If you don't want to rely on other modules (celery etc), you need to manage yourself the state of your job, and store it somewhere. I store it in the DB so that pending jobs can be resumed after a restart of the server.

Note that you must NOT perform CPU intensive computations in the `background_tasks` of the app, because it runs in the same async event loop that serves the requests and it will stall your app. Instead submit them to a thread pool or a process pool.

Comment: Such a great idea storing the task status on the DB. I've just implemented it and it's working beautifully, the task itself is responsible for updating it's status. Thanks. This should be the main answer, as it really solves the problem.

Also: remember to check for failures on startup in case the app breaks. I'm using Fastapi Events: startup to mark all unsuccessful tasks as failed

Comment: Thank you.
It works great for me also. Care must be taken with concurrent access to the DB to update the status though. I ran into some trouble with sqlAlchemy Sessions, I had to read the documentation carefully. You can't use the dependency from the examples of fastAPI, you need to create a new session in the function that is ran in the separate thread or process.

Comment: Would anyone care to post a MWE with this setup? Or at least link to somewhere that shows an example. It seems very interesting but I, for one, haven't the slightest ideia how to begin this.

Answer (score 8):

Try this pattern:

```
import time
from fastapi import BackgroundTasks, FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

class TaskState:

    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = 0

    def background_work(self):
        while True:
            self.counter += 1
            time.sleep(1)

    def get_state(self):
        return self.counter

state = TaskState()

@app.post("/post_job", status_code=HTTP_201_CREATED)
async def send_notification(background_tasks: BackgroundTasks):
    background_tasks.add_task(state.background_work)
    return {"message": "Job Created, check status after some time!"}

@app.get("/get_status")
def status():
    return state.get_state()
```

Comment: Oh jesus! This is a concurrency nightmare.
TaskState is global, and there is no locking mechanism, if multiple send_notifications are getting triggered, then you are in big trouble.

Comment: This only works if you have one worker.