# FastApi Background Task kill

Tags: python, multithreading, background, fastapi

Is there any way to end from a DELETE endpoint a FastApi BackgroundTask I added in a POST?

For example:
Taking this example from [FastAPI tutorial](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/background-tasks/#using-backgroundtasks):

```
from fastapi import BackgroundTasks, FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


def write_notification(email: str, message=""):
    with open("log.txt", mode="w") as email_file:
        content = f"notification for {email}: {message}"
        email_file.write(content)


@app.post("/send-notification/{email}")
async def send_notification(email: str, background_tasks: BackgroundTasks):
    background_tasks.add_task(write_notification, email, message="some notification")
    return {"message": "Notification sent in the background"}
```

What is the proper way to permanently kill all non-finished `write_notifaction` calls added as background tasks?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61836761/get-return-status-from-background-tasks-in-fastapi

Answer (score 1):

I think an elegant solution is not currently possible by default in FastApi.
You can use [Celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/getting-started/introduction.html) to complete this task.

Check out this [example](https://testdriven.io/blog/fastapi-and-celery/).They address the difference between Celery vs BackgroundTasks.

Also, you can find more details about this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61836761/get-return-status-from-background-tasks-in-fastapi).